# Elementor button doesn´t work at 1st click

Tags: wordpress, elementor

I have a website with a platform registration button. My problem is that when I open the web logged-out and click on that button, I reload the page again. Then if I try to click there if it works for me.

I appreciate any information on this error.

Website: https://seocrawl.com/

Answer (score 0):

check if the the homepage and the registration links have the same permlinks

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).